# put image in thunderbird signature

Tags: images, thunderbird, email-signature

I would like to put a small image in my Thunderbird signature.  I edited signature.html to add the false stuff, but the image still doesn't appear.

```
<img moz-do-not-send="false" alt= etc. etc.>
```

Any suggestions? (step by step, please)

Answer (score 11):

#### How to use an image as Thunderbird signature

1. Put the image file in C:\ and rename it to image (for convenience)
2. Open Notepad
3. Type these HTML codes

   ```
   <b>Jhon Cena</b>
   <br><img moz-do-not-send="false" src="file:///C:/image.gif" alt="Signature">
   ```
4. Save it to C:\ as Test.html
5. You should have 2 files in C:\ drive: image.gif and Test.html
6. Open Mozilla Thunderbird and login to your account
7. Go to *Tools* Menu and select *Account Settings*
8. Highlight your account
9. Tick the option *Attach the signature from a file instead (text, html or image)*
10. Click on *Choose*, navigate to C:, open Test.html and click OK
11. To Test if its working, simply write a mail by clicking *Write* Button

[image]
<sup>tested on Windows XP Pro SP3</sup>

Comment: Note here i have used a image.gif file, if you are using .jpeg or .bmp or any other image file then please change the extension appropriately in the html file. By the way the 1st line in the html code is to enter your name in text and the 2nd line is for the image. If you don't want your name in text then simply skip the 1st line.