# Placing image on the signature in thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

This is a follow-up on the question "[put image in thunderbird signature](https://superuser.com/questions/187802)".

Is there a way to make the inserted image independent of the local file?

If I delete/move the image file's, it can no longer be seen in the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Create html signature and insert image as described at Mozilla support site.

[Mozilla Support/Thunderbird/Signatures/Including image files in signatures](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/signatures#w_signatures-stored-in-files)

Comment: Yes, tried that. Doesn't seem to work. The image from signature disappears as soon as the file on the local drive is modified/moved.