# how to put an image in an HTML signature for Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, jpeg, email-signature, base64

How do I get thunderbird to [send HTML **and** an image](https://superuser.com/questions/187802/put-image-in-thunderbird-signature/187811) in a signature?

Just wanting to send a [red dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) in the signature file for as an example.

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/44481019/262852

Comment: forgot to enable HTML messages as per:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/100797/how-do-i-configure-thunderbird-to-send-plain-text-emails-by-default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The url of the img is only valid to your computer and it is not valid at the receiver side. So you need to encode the image file using a base64 encoder like this [one](https://www.base64-image.de/).

> Upload the signature and convert it into base64.
>
> Copy the code and replace the path in img tag with the code like
>   this.

```
<br><img src="data:image/bmp;base64,Qk32BgAAAAAA...." alt="Signature">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated the question a bit.  Need to use src="data:...." ?  Don't want to include the file itself directly.

Comment: @Thufir If your are not ready to include file itself directly then the image will only be visible to you. Others won't be able to see your image. For that you need to embed the image and send.

Comment: what I mean is I'd like to use `file:///whatever` instead of directly pasting the *data*.  I wrote incorrectly about including the *file* directly.  Of course I want to include the file, but would want to refer by file name and path.  is that possible?

Comment: @Thufir Does your email recipient have access to this path? If not then they won't be able to see this file. For them you must embed the image and send or serve from your website or public server

Comment: ohhhhhh, that's weird, didn't think of that.  thx.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60262/discussion-between-thufir-and-codeit).

Comment: Images inserted like this are not visible in gmail for example. With how widespread gmail is this cannot be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

syntax is fine:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat .tbird/sig.html

this is in <i>italics</i>
<br>
and something <em>emphasized</em>
<br>
here's some <b>bold</b>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<img moz-do-not-send="false" src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" 

style="height:22px; width:22px"
alt="Signature"/>

thufir@doge:~$
```

forgot to enable HTML e-mail:

https://askubuntu.com/q/100797/45156

copied in reference from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44482049/262852

Comment: Images inserted like this are not visible in gmail for example. With how widespread gmail is this cannot be an acceptable answer.

Comment: how does gmail handle inserted images, then?

Comment: It basically removes src attribut out of html (if it contains such inline data instead of http*) before displaying message, and the <img> image without it is displayed as if it had broken url.